# SSR and Lazy load in angular universal are not working as expected

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have an application with Angular Universal and GraphQL.

For reducing the bundle size we want to implement a component lazy load. Which at first works good. For that we use a 'Dynamic Component' that loads all these modules:

this my dynamic-component.component.ts:

```
import {
Component,
ComponentFactoryResolver,
ElementRef,
HostListener,
Input,
ViewChild,
ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { WPComponentAdvancedFields } from 'src/app/pages/master/master/master.model';
import { PlatformService } from '../../services/platform/platform.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-dynamic-component',
templateUrl: './dynamic-component.component.html',
styleUrls: \['./dynamic-component.component.scss'\],
})
export class DynamicComponentComponent {
@Input() name: string = '';
@Input() data: Record\<string, any\> = {};
@Input() advanced: WPComponentAdvancedFields = {
anchor: '',
className: '',
};
didScrollIntoView: boolean = false;
hasScrolled: boolean = false;
dontRender: boolean = false;

@ViewChild('dynamicContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef })
private dynamicContainerRef!: ViewContainerRef;

currentElement = this.elref.nativeElement.querySelector(`.js-${this.name}`);
intersectionObserverOffset = {
root: this.currentElement,
rootMargin: '0px 0px 400px 0px'
}

//Wait to scroll in lazy load components.
@HostListener('window:scroll', \['$event'\])
onScroll(event: Event) {
if (!this.hasScrolled) {
this.hasScrolled = true;
}
}

constructor(
private vcref: ViewContainerRef,
private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver,
private ps: PlatformService,
private elref: ElementRef
) {}

//Min height exclusion.
//We need a min height to prevent CLS
componentsWithNoMinHeight = \[
'acf/zip-search',
'acf/wysiwyg',
'acf/banner-bar',
'acf/breadcrumbs',
'acf/locations-filters'
\]

//Some components increase the Blocking time due to their long time loading.
//We bet for lazy loading those:
componentsWithLazyLoad = \[
'acf/product-wizard',
'acf/product-industry-filter',
'acf/product-service-filter',
'acf/product-brand-filter'
\];

onIntersection({ visible }: { visible: boolean }){
if (this.hasScrolled && this.ps.isBrowser() && visible && !this.didScrollIntoView) {
this.didScrollIntoView = true;
this.showComponents();
}
}

ngOnInit() {
if( !this.componentsWithLazyLoad.includes(this.name) ){
this.showComponents();
}
}

showComponents(): void {
let inputs: any;
switch (this.name) {
case 'acf/three-card-row':
inputs = {
variant: this.data\['variant'\],
title: this.data\['title'\],
cards: this.data\['cards'\],
};
this.loadThreeCardRowComponent(inputs);
break;
case 'acf/breadcrumbs':
inputs = {
paths: this.data\['paths'\],
};
this.loadBreadcrumbsComponent(inputs);
break;
case 'acf/full-width-hero--blur':
case 'acf/full-width-hero--card':
case 'acf/full-width-hero--transparency':
inputs = {
variant: this.data\['variant'\],
responsiveImgs: this.data\['responsiveImgs'\],
card: this.data\['card'\],
banner: this.data\['banner'\],
textColor: this.data\['textColor'\],
animated: this.data\['animated'\],
};
this.loadFWHeroComponent(inputs);
break;
default:
inputs = {
text: 'Component was not found, is not yet supported, or there was an unexpected error',
};
this.loadDefault(inputs);
break;
}
}

async loadBreadcrumbsComponent(inputs: any) {
this.vcref.clear();
const { BreadcrumbsComponent } = await import(
'../../../blocks/components/breadcrumbs/breadcrumbs.component'
);
let threecardrowcomp = this.dynamicContainerRef.createComponent(
this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(BreadcrumbsComponent)
);

    threecardrowcomp.instance.paths = inputs.paths;

}
async loadThreeCardRowComponent(inputs: any) {
this.vcref.clear();
const { ThreeCardRowComponent } = await import(
'../../../blocks/components/three-card-row/three-card-row.component'
);
let threecardrowcomp = this.dynamicContainerRef.createComponent(
this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(ThreeCardRowComponent)
);

    threecardrowcomp.instance.title = inputs.title;
    threecardrowcomp.instance.variant = inputs.variant;
    threecardrowcomp.instance.cards = inputs.cards;

}

async loadFWHeroComponent(inputs: any) {
this.vcref.clear();
const { FwHeroComponent } = await import(
'../../../blocks/components/fw-hero/fw-hero.component'
);
let currentComponent = this.dynamicContainerRef.createComponent(
this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(FwHeroComponent)
);

    currentComponent.instance.variant = inputs.variant;
    currentComponent.instance.responsiveImgs = inputs.responsiveImgs;
    currentComponent.instance.card = inputs.card;
    currentComponent.instance.banner = inputs.banner;
    currentComponent.instance.textColor = inputs.textColor;
    currentComponent.instance.animated = inputs.animated;

}
}
```

And this is my dynamic-component.html

```
<div
  *ngIf="!dontRender"
  [id]="this.advanced.anchor"
  [className]="'js-'+this.name +' '+ this.advanced.className"
  [attr.anchor-current]="this.advanced.anchor !== ''"
  [ngClass]="{'dynamic-min-height': !componentsWithNoMinHeight.includes(this.name)}"
  inViewport
  [inViewportOptions]="componentsWithLazyLoad.includes(this.name) ? intersectionObserverOffset : {}"
  (inViewportAction)="componentsWithLazyLoad.includes(this.name) ? onIntersection($event) : null"
>

  <div #dynamicContainer ></div>

</div>
```

The problem goes here:

We don't want to load in cascade the javascript chunks in the client side. Otherwise at first we'd need to show a blank content and half a second later the content loads. That causes issues with CLS performance metrics.

-What we want is to load the content at once, as we think this is the utilization of SSR, not waiting until the different chunks load. Curious thing is that if we check the source code, SSR seems to work, so the content is there, loaded from the beginning but still, we need to wait this JS chunks to make the content appear.

Thanks in advance